# existence of a Lie superalgebra with unsolvable word problem

Tags: lie-algebras, lie-superalgebras

In the book entitled "Algorithmic and Combinatorial Algebra" written by Bukot and Kukin and they showed that there exists a finitely presented Lie algebra with unsolvable word problem. Can we conclude same result for the case of Lie superalgebras?

Comment: Every Lie algebra is in particular a (purely even) Lie superalgebra, so yes.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you